Is there a countable model of NBG set theory where every set but not every class is definable?
Does there exist a countable model of NBG set theory, such that every set is first-order definable without parameters, but not every class is definable? If so, can someone prove it?

I suspect you can start with some pointwise definable model (e.g. the minimal model) and force with something like $\mathrm{Add(Ord,1)}$.
